Symmetry of Green's function inside a rectangular cavity with Perfect Electric Conductor (Boundary) and metallic scatterers within them
An elementary dipole source generates electromagnetic waves at a specific frequency inside a rectangular cavity whose sides are Perfect Electric Conductors. Few scatters are present inside the cavity, which are linear, homogeneous and isotropic. Their relative permeability is 1.
Can anyone please explain what will happen to the symmetry of the green's functions when the scatterers have some small electrical conductivity (so that power is dissipated as heat)?
It is usually said that the Green's function is not symmetric within the cavity. However, when simulated in COMSOL, I can get the same electric field when the source and measurement points are interchanged.

When the source and measured point are interchanged you see reciprocity of the system. I think that "symmetry" would mean something different to most people. You would have to be much more specific about what you mean (and probably also about the positions of those "few" scatterers that you have.)

The shape and number of scatterers does not seem to affect this behavior. As an example, a cube at the centre of the cavity can be considered. For symmetry of greens function, I mean that g(a,b) = g(b,a).

Swapping input and output, as in $G(a,b)=G(b,a)$ is the kind of symmetry that is usually called [reciprocity].
Another kind of symmetry would be moving the points $a$ and $b$ to other positions which should be equivalent due to the symmetry of the rectangular cavity. This latter symmetry would be broken by scatterers at random positions (i.e. if they are not placed at symmetry points of the cavity).
The former (reciprocity) is always valid for a passive system as long as it is not a [gyrator], and a gyrator would require magnetic materials and a permanent magnetic field. You say magnetic materials are not present, but you only want to give the scatterers electric conductivity. In that case reciprocity will still hold so the $G(a,b)=G(b,a)$ symmetry will still be present.
